# How to run a function when querying a data entity using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How to run a function when querying a data entity using Entity Framework?

```
var name = "First name";
// it throws exception here
var result = contactRepository.Query.FirstOrDefault(x => SanitizeUserInput(x.Name) == name);

public static string SanitizeUserInput(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return string.Empty;

    var htmlDecodedValue = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
    return Regex.Replace(htmlDecodedValue ?? string.Empty, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Query is of type IQueryable.

I get the below error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   SanitizeUserInput(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework works following way - it translates expression tree into SQL text query, and then executes query using old good ADO.NET. Custom functions cannot be translated into SQL by Entity Framework provider. You can run custom function only in-memory:

```
 var result = contactRepository.Query.AsEnumerable()
                 .FirstOrDefault(c => SanitizeUserInput(c.Name) == name);
```

This will generate SQL query for fetching all data from database and execute it. Then you will enumerate results reading DataReader rows one by one, mapping data to your entities and executing `SanitizeUserInput` method until condition is met.

Comment: so basically you mean I'd have to loan all the data in memory then applying the filter. that impacts the performance heavily. I'm thinking maybe adding a SQL Function or stored procedure may perform better?

Comment: @TheLight not always all data will be loaded into memory, as I described above, you will load all data into memory only if there is no data matching your FirstOrDefault criteria. Otherwise you will stop fetching data when match is found. But yes, that's a great performance hit comparing to running pure SQL query

Comment: @TheLight and yes, stored procedure or SQL function will allow you to do all stuff on server side, but that's part where EF cannot help you - you should translate your custom method into SQL manually